# After Vercel production i cant view swagger ui

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, vercel

i created .yaml file and i converted it js form. my codes are written ES6. when i run the app by using vercel cli with

```
vercel-dev
```

i can view swagger ui .but after

```
vercel-prod
```

command i can view my home page and there is link for

```
/api-docs
```

route. but i cant view swagger ui. it says

```
---the stylesheet https://school-management-system-rest-api.vercel.app/api-docs/swagger-ui.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css". api-docs ---Loading failed for the <script> with source "https://school-management-system-rest-api.vercel.app/api-docs/swagger-ui-bundle.js".---he script from "https://school-management-system-rest-api.vercel.app/api-docs/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js" was loaded even though its MIME type ("text/html") is not a valid JavaScript MIME type
```

i tried to move swagger files to public folder. but in that case i have problem with commonJS and ES6 incompatiblity. i need another solutins  i think. i dont have knowladge about babel.

```
const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
const openApiYamlPath = path.join(__dirname, "./public/SchoolManSystemOpenAPI.yaml");
const openapiObject = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync(openApiYamlPath, "utf8"));

const options = {
  swaggerDefinition: openapiObject,
  apis: ["./routes/*.js"],

};

const swaggerSpec = swaggerJsDoc(options);
app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec));
```